# By the way, how was I right?

Tags: polynomials, radicals

My math test had this question:

Solve for $x$: $$\sqrt{8x-12}+\sqrt{32x+52}=10.$$

I solved it as follows:
$$\sqrt{8x-12}+\sqrt{32x+52}=10.$$
Dividing both sides by 2,
$$\sqrt{2x-3}+\sqrt{8x+13}=5.$$
squaring on both sides,
$$(\sqrt{2x-3}+\sqrt{8x+13})^2=25$$
Cancelling square and square roots, we get
$$(2x-3+8x+13)=25$$
$$10x=15$$
$$x=1.5$$

The answer key had the same anwer. So I expected an 'A' grade .

But the teacher gave me 'F' and wrote "Right answer but wrong method" in my answer sheet.

**Can anyone explain why I got the right answer inspite of doing it in a wrong way?**

Comment: How exactly did you cancel the square root and square??

Comment: Squares and square roots are inverses of each other. Hence we can cancel them....(can't you?)

Comment: You mean this $(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})^2 = (a+b)$ ?

Comment: Exactly........

Comment: Try it with some numbers, say $a=4$, $b=1$ ..

Comment: Note that $(\sqrt{2x-\color{red}3}+\sqrt{8x+13})^2=25$

Comment: -1 for non informative title

Comment: @Math_QED---Please suggest an informative title please...

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$(a+b)^2 = a^2 +b^2 +2ab$$

You got it right despite doing $a^2 + b^2$ because in your case $2ab = 0$ i.e. $2(1.5) - 3 =0$.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is at the step: $$\left (\sqrt{2x-3}+\sqrt{8x+13}\right )^2=25$$ Which you, basicly wrote, is equal to: $$(\sqrt{2x-3})^2+(\sqrt{8x+13})^2=25$$

The reason why this gave the right answer, is because $x=1.5$, and so $\sqrt{2x-3}=0$.

In other words, $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2$ if $a=0$.

Comment: Note that $(\sqrt{2x-\color{red}3}+\sqrt{8x+13})^2=25$

Comment: @gimusi Whoah! Thank you!